# Interact with IE element not in the DOM

Tags: html, excel, vba

Dears

I'm trying to automate a task that I'm using VBA to interact with internet explorer.

But I'm stucked in selecting input box that I should put some data and press apply.

But when Press right click on the mouse to get the element ID IE shown this message"The requested element is no longer attached to the DOM".

But when I manually choose "Select Element" then Choose this BOX, the below HTML code is appear

`<input name="_paramsN" title="" class="inputbox" id="_paramsN" onkeyup="this.title = this.value; Form.isMaxLength(this, 4000);" onchange="false" type="text" size="50" value="">`

and that is my VBA code

`

```
Sub Test()
    Const cURL = "https:www.login.jsp?"
    Const cUsername = "XXXX "    'REPLACE XXXX WITH YOUR USER NAME
    Const cPassword = "YYYY "    'REPLACE YYYY WITH YOUR PASSWORD
    
    
    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim doc As htmlDocument
    Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim SignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim element As Object
    Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    With IE
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate cURL
    
      
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    

     Set doc = IE.document
    On Error Resume Next
    doc.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   
    Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)
    
    
    
    Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.elements("j_username")
    UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername
 
    
    'Get the password textbox and populate it
  

    Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("j_Password")
    PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword
    
    'Get the form input button and click it
    
    
    Set SignInButton = LoginForm.elements("btn_login")
    SignInButton.Click
            
    
    
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    IE.navigate "https://https:www.login/ll.jsp
   
     Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
   
      Dim Entry As Object
       Set Entry = IE.document.getElementByClassName("_paramsN")
         Call TriggerEvent(HTMLDoc, Entry, "_paramsN")
        Entry.Value = "4546546645"


    End With
    End Sub
```

after I Put the data in the input Box mentioned, I should extract them as Excel which it's HTML Line is: -

`<div class="itemTxt">Excel (*.xlsx)</div>`

Please notice that i'm new in VBA

thats it.

select and put the data